# Statistical technique to combine scores from multiple tests

Tags: machine-learning, pca, statsmodels

In my experiment I have two groups, one group has an anxiety disorder (N = 22), the other does not (N = 11) (I know low sample size). They were tested in a battery of psychological tests and also biological tests such as scans. The problem is some of the outcome types were different such as continuous, ordinal, binary, counts, and percentages. How would you go about combining all of these tests into a single "score" to help determine how severe the anxiety is? Overall I want to be able to use this scoring system in the future.

Comment: These tests get at different aspects of anxiety, and combining them is not a good idea.  Its like saying "I have 2 iPhones and 1 car. How many dollars do I have?".  You're best to discuss differences between groups as they relate to each measurement.  That is to say, do not pool these measurements into a single measure.

Comment: It is still ok to combine the same types of variables? For example binary variables?

Answer (score 0):

One machine leaning approach would be to assign a score (or a class) to each of our samples. If you're using a continuous score you can then use a regression technique. If your score is more like categories, you can use a classification technique, like random forests. Then in the future you can use your fitted model to calculate the score or predict the class of new data.

But of course, this is if you intend to use machine learning. If you just want to create a way of assigning a score based on a set of variables, then you're free to invent it as you like, as long as you can show that it's consistent.